# Jenkins Pipeline as Code Groovy Error on Class Annotation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I am trying to use Jenkins pipeline as code (formally workflow). I am getting errors whenever I try to use Annotations on a class defined in the pipeline script.

Error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during canonicalization: Unexpected variable type: null

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unexpected variable type: null
```

JenkinsFile

```
import groovy.transform.ToString;
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode;
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
class BarDeploy {
    String barFile
    String app
    String integrationServer    
}
```

Any ideas why I cannot do this?

Full Stack Trace

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during canonicalization: Unexpected variable type: null

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unexpected variable type: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitVariableExpression(CpsTransformer.groovy:723)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression.visit(VariableExpression.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression$visit.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression$visit.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.groovy:234)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor546.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:361)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$_visitBinaryExpression_closure25.doCall(CpsTransformer.groovy:553)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor569.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$_visitBinaryExpression_closure25.doCall(CpsTransformer.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor568.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.groovy:278)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor545.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.groovy:253)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor544.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitBinaryExpression(CpsTransformer.groovy:559)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression.visit(BinaryExpression.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression$visit.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement$visit.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.groovy:234)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor546.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(CpsTransformer.groovy:395)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement$visit.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.StaticMethodCallExpression$visit.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.groovy:234)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor546.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.groovy:240)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor552.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:361)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$_visitBlockStatement_closure8.doCall(CpsTransformer.groovy:342)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor580.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$_visitBlockStatement_closure8.doCall(CpsTransformer.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor579.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.groovy:278)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor545.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.groovy:253)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor544.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitBlockStatement(CpsTransformer.groovy:341)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement$visit.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression$visit.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.groovy:234)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor546.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visit(CpsTransformer.groovy:240)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor552.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:361)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$_visitBlockStatement_closure8.doCall(CpsTransformer.groovy:342)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor580.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$_visitBlockStatement_closure8.doCall(CpsTransformer.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor579.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeChildren(CpsTransformer.groovy:278)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor545.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.makeNode(CpsTransformer.groovy:253)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor544.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitBlockStatement(CpsTransformer.groovy:341)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement$visit.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.visitMethod(CpsTransformer.groovy:166)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor606.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:361)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer$_call_closure1.doCall(CpsTransformer.groovy:95)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor605.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:903)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1379)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1351)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods$each.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods$each.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.groovy:26)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor582.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ReflectionMetaMethod.invoke(ReflectionMetaMethod.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.NewInstanceMetaMethod.invoke(NewInstanceMetaMethod.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callSafe(AbstractCallSite.java:82)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsTransformer.call(CpsTransformer.groovy:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:970)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:548)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:503)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:302)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:281)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:106)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:376)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:343)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:212)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:997)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:548)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:503)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:302)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:281)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:106)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:376)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:343)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:212)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I just ran up against this....

Comment: No, I ended up removing the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is known about, and still open, in Jenkins.  See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40564